# Getting comma separated values into input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am struggling already for some time to create script that deletes and adds values to field. The point is that when I click on div - there will be images inside, it will copy part of its class to field, or remove if it's already copied there. All the values in field `input_8_3` need to be comma separated without spaces except the last one and in case there is only one value there shouldn't be any comma. The same with field `input_8_4`, but there I need only erased values.

In addition I need divs to change class on click, one click to add class, another to remove it, but this is how far could I get with my issue.

I need this for deleting images in custom field in Wordpresses frontend. `input_8_3` goes to meta and `input_8_4` to array in function to delete chosen images.

Thanks in advance!

```js
(function($){
$('.thumbn').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).attr("id").replace('img-act-','')+',';
    var oldtext = $('#input_8_3').val();
    $('#input_8_3').val(text+oldtext);
});
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$('div.thumbn').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('chosen-img');
});
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$('.thumbn').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('chosen-img');
});
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.thumbn {
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    background: #7ef369;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
.chosen-img.thumbn{background:#727272}
input{width:100%}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input_8_3" readonly="" value="3014,3015,3016,3017,3018" class="form-control data_lable">
<input type="text" id="input_8_4" readonly="" value="" class="form-control data_lable">

<div class="user-profile-avatar user_seting st_edit">
<div>
<div class="thumbn" id="img-act-3014"></div>
<div class="thumbn" id="img-act-3015"></div>
<div class="thumbn" id="img-act-3016"></div>
<div class="thumbn" id="img-act-3017"></div>
<div class="thumbn" id="img-act-3018"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I changed value of `input_8_3`. All the numbers in `img-act-****` and values in `input_8_3` are the same on load.

Comment: First of all you have two click functions that's basically on the same thing, so the last one (add class) is going to be the one triggering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a JS of it working.

https://jsfiddle.net/jatwm8sL/6/

I've added these:

```
var array = [3008,3009,3010,3011,3012];

$("#input_8_3").val(array.join());
```

and changed your click functions to this

```
var array = [3008,3009,3010,3011,3012];
var array1 = [];

$("#input_8_3").val(array.join());

(function($){
$('div.thumbn').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).attr("id").replace('img-act-','');
  var oldtext = $('#input_8_3').val();
    if ($(this).hasClass('chosen-img'))
  {
    $('#input_8_3').val(text+oldtext);      
    var index = array.indexOf(text);
    if (index !== -1)
    {
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }

    array1.push(text);
    $(this).removeClass('chosen-img');
  }
  else
  {
    array.push(text);
    var index = array1.indexOf(text);
    if (index !== -1)
    {
        array1.splice(index, 1);
    }
    $(this).addClass('chosen-img');
  }
  $("#input_8_3").val(array.join());
  $("#input_8_4").val(array1.join());
  console.log(array1);
});
})(jQuery);
```

Basically, you need to check if it has a class and then remove if it has and add it if it doesn't.

Also, it's better to use a javascript array than to play around with html values as you change javascript arrays while HTML should really just display them.

If anything is unclear, let me know and I'll try to explain myself better

Comment: Also use a jsfiddle next time as it's easier for us to play around

Comment: Thank you. The field `input_8_3` is getting value from sql, and with $POST is updating its changed value, that's why I wanted it receive it there. Unfortunetelly it's still putting commas at the end. IDs `img-act-****` are getting the same values as value of `#input_8_3` on load.

Comment: There was still the `+','` I've removed it now. There's no more trailing commas.

Comment: So actually when I click on DIV, particular old values should disappear from the field. There are no new values to enter - in each case numbers from classes will be the same as the ones in field.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly the reason why the 3008-12 values are showing up is because of `var array = [3008,3009,3010,3011,3012];` If you set that it empty then it should disappear. If that's not what you mean, you might need to explain a bit more.

Comment: The values in array stand for the id's of divs (sorry for confusion). The value of `#input_8_3` together with divs classes are taken from database. In each div there is a picture, which (its number) on click should be erased from `#input_8_3` and updated when I submit the form. Same with field `#input_8_4` - this values are going with subission to function that deletes pictures with given ID.

Comment: Well I can't do anything about your database since I won't have access to it. But what I've given you, you should be able to implement whatever it is you want to do. Values get added and removed depending on when it's clicked. You may need to update your code to match what you want to do if we're going to get any further.

Comment: that wasn't the point :P I've created some confusion since in my example I have different numbers in the field and for DIVs. In fact they are the same. My point was just to make sth eg. value of field `value="1,2,3,4,5"` and when I click on div `img-act-2` number 2 dissapears from the field, and if I click on it again it will appear there again. That's for `#input_8_3`. Input `#input_8_4` should get only values that has been deleted from `#input_8_3`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm sorry to be such a pain in.. but: Is there any way to work on input value instead of var array? In addition DIVs numbers and field value should be the same, and values that are there from the start  should be deleted on click - not added on click and then deleted on click. Right now I am getting **first:** `3014,3015,3016,3017,3018` then on **click on first div**:  `3014,3015,3016,3017,3018,3014` and when **click back again:** `3014,3015,3016,3017,3018` and **should get** `3015,3016,3017,3018`

Comment: You could do it via input value by getting the val using jquery then parsing it into an array, and what not. For the other issue, can you throw it onto a jsfiddle? Because your issue does not happen with mine.

Comment: can the initial var array be empty?

Comment: After some tweaking i managed to reach what I wanted :) But of course thanks to you :) https://jsfiddle.net/xqxk2qdg/6/

Comment: ezpz, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var transformNumbers = (function () {
    var numerals = {
        persian: ["۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹"],
        arabic: ["٠", "١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩"]
    };
    function fromEnglish(str, lang) {
        var i, len = str.length, result = "";

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
            result += numerals[lang][str[i]];
        return result;
    }
    return {
        toNormal: function (str) {
            var num, i, len = str.length, result = "";

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                num = numerals["persian"].indexOf(str[i]);
                num = num != -1 ? num : numerals["arabic"].indexOf(str[i]);
                if (num == -1) num = str[i];
                result += num;
            }
            return result;
        },
        toPersian: function (str, lang) {
            return fromEnglish(str, "persian");
        },
        toArabic: function (str) {
            return fromEnglish(str, "arabic");
        }
    }
})();
  document.getElementById('ApproximateValue').addEventListener('input', event =>
            event.target.value = TolocalInt(event.target.value)
        );
        function TolocalInt(value)
        {
            if ((value.replace(/,/g, '')).length >= 9) {
                value = value.replace(/,/g, '').substring(0, 9);
            }
            var hasZero = false;
            var value = transformNumbers.toNormal(value);
            var result = (parseInt(value.replace(/[^\d]+/gi, '')) || 0);
            if (hasZero) {
                result = '0' + (result.toString());
            }
            return result.toLocaleString('en-US');
        }
```

```html
<input id="ApproximateValue" name="ApproximateValue"  type="text" maxlength="12" />
```